# How to fix 'singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates' error with nls () for the Richards equation

Tags: r

I am trying to fit the Richards model in R for this data bellow but can't get it to work.

```
time Volume
     3     12
     6     25
     9     38
    12     53
    15     73
    21    108
    27    136
    33    160
    39    180
    48    202
    60    222
    72    241
    96    255
```

```r
Richards <- nls(
    Volume ~ (Vi*Vf)/((Vi^n) + ((Vf^n-(Vi^n))*exp(-u*time)))^(1/n), 
    data=dat1, 
    start=c(Vi=3, Vf=255, u=6, n=-0.5))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That seems like an unconventional/non-standard definition of [Richard's curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function); are you sure this is correct? Can you provide a reference for the function definition as used here?

Comment: More to the point of your question: From Cross Validated ["Automatically finding good starting values for a nonlinear model is an art"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160552/why-is-nls-giving-me-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estimates); we can usually get a decent idea about sensible starting values for (some of the) parameters by looking at asymptotes, inflection points etc. Which is why I'm asking whether the definition of Richard's curve as given here is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use `dput` to provide data since it is quicker to get into R and preserves data types such as integer and factor:

```
dat1 <- structure(list(time = c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 21L, 27L, 33L, 
    39L, 48L, 60L, 72L, 96L), Volume = c(12L, 25L, 38L, 53L, 73L, 
    108L, 136L, 160L, 180L, 202L, 222L, 241L, 255L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Here are the data and the curve you are trying to fit with your starting values:

```
plot(Volume~time, dat1)
Vi <- 3; Vf <- 255; u <- 6; n <- -0.5
Vol.pred <- (Vi*Vf)/((Vi^n) + ((Vf^n-(Vi^n))*exp(-u*dat1$time)))^(1/n)
lines(dat1$time, Vol.pred, col="red")
```

You can see the predicted line is nowhere near the data. As @Maurits Evers indicated, it is not clear that the Richard's curve is appropriate, but you can try changing the starting values to get something closer, e.g. by changing `u` to .05:

```
lines(dat1$time, Vol.pred, col="blue")
```

That gives us starting values that will work:

```
Richards <- nls(
   Volume ~ (Vi*Vf)/((Vi^n) + ((Vf^n-(Vi^n))*exp(-u*time)))^(1/n), 
   data=dat1, 
   start=c(Vi=3, Vf=255, u=.05, n=-0.5))
lines(dat1$time, predict(Richards), col="darkgreen")
```

[image: NLS fit]